# QML Text objects missing spaces after commas or periods in iOS 14

Tags: ios, qt, qml, ios14

With QML based applications iOS 14 - for any `Text` elements that contain a space following a comma or period - the space does not appear.  Has anyone else run into this?

If I change the text to be **two** spaces after a comma, then a single space does appear in v14 but appears as two spaces in v12 & v13 (only the first space after a period or comma is lost).

In the image below the left-hand side shows a simulation in iOS 12.1 where the spaces appear normal, the right-hand side shows a simulation in iOS 14.0 where the spaces go missing.  iOS 13.7 (not pictured) appears similar to v12.1.

```
import QtQuick 2.12 
import QtQuick.Window 2.12 

Window { 
    width: 640 
    height: 480 
    visible: true 
    title: qsTr("Hello World") 
    Text { 
        id: textID 
        text: qsTr("I, am, some. text. Here. Is a double space.") 
    } 
}
```

[image: iOS 12 vs 14 - space after punctuation missing]

**Qt**: v5.15.0 
**XCode**: v12.0.1
**MacOS**: Catalina v10.15.7

Comment: I guess that's a bug, report it at https://bugreports.qt.io/ .
Does it also happen on a real device with iOS 14?

Comment: Yes, it also happens on real devices.

Comment: Did you report it? I see the same bug.

Comment: Yes, this was reported.  See: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-86995  https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-86496  and  https://codereview.qt-project.org/c/qt/qtbase/+/322102